# How to make matrix multiplication with cython + scipy.linalg.cython_blas as fast as numpy.dot?

Tags: numpy, cython, matrix-multiplication

```py
import numpy as np
```

I want to multiply two matrices

```py
a = np.random.randn(n_dim, n_dim) + 1j * np.random.randn(n_dim, n_dim)
b = np.random.randn(n_dim, n_dim) + 1j * np.random.randn(n_dim, n_dim)
```

My baseline function is `np.dot` with which I compute `c = np.dot(a, b)`.

I'm assuming that `np.dot` calls the BLAS function [`zgemm`](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/d17/group__complex16__blas__level3_ga4ef748ade85e685b8b2241a7c56dd21c.html). For this reason, I was hoping to be able to write a cython function involving `zgemm` which performs as well as `np.dot`.

Here is my cython function:

```
# cython: language_level=3
# cython: infer_types=False
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport scipy.linalg.cython_blas as blas
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def func(double complex[:, ::1] a, double complex[:, ::1] b):

    cdef:
        int m, n, k, lda, ldb, ldc
        double complex[:, ::1] cv
        double complex alpha, beta
    m = a.shape[0]
    n = b.shape[1]
    k = a.shape[1]
    lda = a.shape[0]
    ldb = b.shape[0]
    ldc = a.shape[0]

    alpha = 1 + 0j
    beta = 0 + 0j

    c = np.empty((n, m), dtype=np.complex128)
    cv = c

    # zgemm computes: C = alpha * op(A) * op(B) + beta * C
    # zgemm's arguments are: TRANSA, TRANSB, M, N, K, ALPHA, A, LDA, B, LDB, BETA, C, LDC
    blas.zgemm('N', 'N', &n, &m, &k, &alpha, &b[0, 0], &ldb, &a[0, 0], &lda, &beta, &cv[0, 0], &ldc)

    return c
```

Note, since `a` and `b` are C-ordered arrays but `zgemm` wants F-ordered arrays, instead of computing `a @ b`, I compute `(b.T @ a.T).T` in an attempt to avoid array copies.

A timing of `np.dot(a, b)` and `func(a, b)` yields

```py
n_dim = 10
  1.7 µs ±   3.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000000 loops each) (np.dot)
  2.0 µs ±  43.28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000000 loops each) (func)
n_dim = 50
 83.5 µs ± 398.63 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each) (np.dot)
 84.7 µs ± 666.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each) (func)
n_dim = 100
123.8 µs ±   3.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each) (np.dot)
124.1 µs ±   1.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each) (func)
n_dim = 500
  4.8 ms ±  58.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each) (np.dot)
  5.1 ms ±   6.00 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each) (func)
n_dim = 1000
 31.3 ms ±  48.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each) (np.dot)
 32.9 ms ± 153.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each) (func)
```

On the one hand, the performance is comparable. On the other hand, I would like `func` to always be at least as good as `np.dot` because it does the same computations with less checking. Or does it?

How can `func` be made faster? Is there for example a better way to allocate the output array `c`?

### Update

There is some improvement after replacing `np.empty` with `np.PyArray_EMPTY` from [NumPy's C API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/array.html#creating-arrays). Further, it was beneficial to use `np.ndarray[np.complex128_t, ndim=2]` instead of `double complex[:, ::1]`. This leads to the following function:

```py
# cython: language_level=3
# cython: infer_types=False
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport scipy.linalg.cython_blas as blas
cimport cython

np.import_array()

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def func1(np.ndarray[np.complex128_t, ndim=2] a, np.ndarray[np.complex128_t, ndim=2] b):

    cdef:
        int k, m, n
        double complex alpha, beta

    m = a.shape[0]
    k = a.shape[1]
    n = b.shape[1]

    alpha = 1 + 0j
    beta = 0 + 0j

    cdef:
        np.npy_intp *dims = [m, n]
        np.ndarray[np.complex128_t, ndim=2] c = np.PyArray_EMPTY(2, dims, np.NPY_COMPLEX128, 0)

    blas.zgemm('N', 'N', &n, &m, &k, &alpha, &b[0, 0], &n, &a[0, 0], &k, &beta, &c[0, 0], &n)

    return c
```

A timing yields

```py
n_dim = 10
  1.7 µs ±   3.88 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000000 loops each) (dot)
  1.1 µs ±  34.48 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000000 loops each) (func1)
n_dim = 50
 89.1 µs ±   2.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000000 loops each) (dot)
 89.3 µs ± 208.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000000 loops each) (func1)
n_dim = 100
135.5 µs ± 105.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each) (dot)
127.9 µs ±  37.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 100000 loops each) (func1)
n_dim = 500
  4.8 ms ±   3.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each) (dot)
  5.2 ms ±   4.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each) (func1)
n_dim = 1000
 31.8 ms ±  55.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each) (dot)
 33.4 ms ±  62.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each) (func1)
```

Comment: For `n_dim = 50` and `n_dim = 100`, the standard deviation is higher than the gap between the two functions to we cannot state that one is statistically slower than the other. in this case. For `n_dim = 10`, I think both function are inefficient and it should be better to implement that yourself. The timings are so small that thing like functions calls becomes expensive. For `n_dim >= 500`, results are surprising. I do not see why Cython could be slower than Numpy since Numpy is supposed to use the same method.

Comment: Note that `dtype=np.complex128` create a dict which can make the cython version a bit slower for `n_dim = 10`. The `np.empty` has an overhead that Numpy does not have (Numpy can directly create the array in C without calling itself from the slow Python interface). Note that some machine can be impacted by the order of the benchmark. Is the difference the same if you change the order of the test?

Comment: You're right about the cases `n_dim = 50` and `n_dim = 100`, thanks. I tried to get rid of the `np.empty` overhead by making the array with `c = np.PyArray_EMPTY(2, dims, np.NPY_COMPLEX128, 0)` and `np.ndarray[np.complex128_t, ndim=2] cv = c`. This brings the `n_dim = 10`-time down to `1.2 µs`. The cases `n_dim = 50` and `n_dim = 100` improve slightly. However, there is no difference in the case `n_dim = 500`.
Changing the evaluation order does not make a difference in my case.